# Optical fiber modem with fiber output

Tags: fiber, modem

Is there a modem that has a fiber optic output?

I have an internet connection, where I receive the signal via fiber optic, I already have a modem, but the output of the modem is RJ45, and on my computer has an input for fiber optics, So I would like to use this fiber input...

Answer (score 0):

A "modem" is used for **mo**dulating and **dem**odulating a broadband signal to/from a cable (DOCSIS) or telephone wire (xDSL). On fiber, there's no modulation.

What you're referring to is probably the **router** that's providing your network with Internet access. Fiber-capable routers ususally have modular fiber ports ([SFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver)) where various transceivers can be plugged in.

If your router (likely) doesn't have an SFP port for the LAN side, you can either

1. replace the router with a model featuring an SFP port where you can plug the fiber transceiver of your choice (assuming 1000BASE-SX)
2. use a media converter from e.g. 1000BASE-T to 1000BASE-SX

1000BASE-SX is gigabit Ethernet for short reach, there's a number of different PHYs for other speeds and ranges. Also, make sure you know what kind of connectors you need (ST, SC, or LC).